# Editing/creating new Normal.mxt template in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, mxd

I used to work with .mxt templates often back in version 9 and 8 but things seems to have changed since then.

I realized that my new documents are loading a style file I don't want to to be loaded in any of my new documents but I am unable to simply unchecked it in the style manager - it always comes back. (This is a style file somehow autimatically generated by Geosoft Target, a geological drillhole management software which I need to have installed on the machine.) Before I contact Geosoft I wanted to try if I can prevent ArmMap it from loading this custom style by removing it from the mxt template itself.

This is not as easy as I've envisioned since there is no Save As mxt option in version 10.1.

I saved my document as Normal.mxd into the \AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcMap\Templates  folder and deleted the Normal.mxt.  *(As per ESRI: Any map document (.mxd) can be used as a map template.)*

Starting ArcMap generated a new Normal.mxt in the "Templates" directory ignoring the Normal.mxd I saved there.

Changing the Normal.mxd extension to mxt results in ArcMap launching a completely blank document.

**How can I edit the existing mxt or create a new mxt?**

Comment: any update? Is it possible to create the *.mxt files ?

Comment: Can you create a new .mxt in ArcGIS 10.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have found you cannot create new *.mxt files at ArcGIS 10.1.

To get a better understanding of how to save customisations in the Normal template at ArcGIS 10.1 perhaps start at the [Fundamentals of saving your customizations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00v000000005000000) page in the documentation.

Comment: So I guess only the existing template can be customized and then in only a very few ways.  Enabling or disabling specific style files from loading into a new document is then not possible.  "...your administrator would customize the Normal template, then copy that Normal.mxt file to the..." Seems like a step backwards from being able to create templates.  But so is not being able to save VBA customization in the Normal template anymore.

Comment: I have found I can save many but not all customizations in the normal.mxt.  One of these I couldn't save in it was a VBA script.  Then I save the remaining customizations (including the VBA script with a button to activate it) in a normal.mxd and use that as the template for all new projects.  Existing projects won't show these additional normal.mxd customizations, although I can customize them and save them.