# How to prevent ArcCatalog's "create pyramids" popup from appearing every session

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arccatalog

For some reason, my ArcCatalog isn't remembering the setting for "always create pyramids".

I see this dialog whenever I try to preview a raster without pyramids (in a new ArcCatalog session) despite hitting "use my choice and do not show this dialog in the future". The setting lasts for this ArcCatalog session, but is forgotten when I close and restart.

[image]

Is there a registry setting or similar to control this?

Comment: I just noticed this also applies to ArcMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another place to control this, but if that dialog isn't sticking I don't know if it will from here either.  In both ArcMap and ArcCatalog, under Customize > Options there is a Raster tab with a radio choice for Prompt, Always, and Never.

Possible bug based on [this forum post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/106933-Endless-prompting-to-build-pyramids)?

I can confirm/replicate the behavior on my 10.2.1 install.

Comment: Good suggestion - but that setting is also reverting to "always prompt" each time I open a new ArcCatalog session. To my knowledge this is a standard ArcGIS installation

Comment: It definitely looks like a bug - thanks for sharing the Esri forum post.

Comment: I have found that if you launch the application as administrator, actually right click the icon and select "Run as administrator" that it will remember the preference when you check the box.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Good suggestion, but I tried that and no effect. Had it worked it would suggest the setting is stored somewhere other than the normals or there is a bug specific to Windows UAC. It's interesting that it's *only* that setting that I've run across so far that it won't save.

Answer (score 0):

The standard setup for ArcMap sessions is controlled by the Normal.mxt file; basically the template .mxd file for a machine. If you open this .mxt file just like any other .mxd document and change settings to Arc they should take effect whenever you open Arc when not opening via a presaved .mxd file, where those settings have been overwritten via changing them and saving to an .mxd.

If you do the what Chris W answered but when in an Arc session by opening your Normal.mxt file, i.e. navigate to Customize --> ArcMap Options --> Raster and select 'Always build pyramids and don't prompt in the future' (or any option you want) and apply the settings it should take effect when opening Arc in future sessions.

I am on a Windows 7 machine using Arc 10.1 and my Normal.mxt file is located in ***\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcMap\Templates**

I am not certain if it makes a difference but when you navigate to the *\AppData\Roaming\ESRI folder (or its equivalent) you should probably delete any previous arc version folders to be certain that they are not causing a miscommunication, probably an oversight but that is junk anyways and should be removed.

Comment: I don't think this applies because for ArcCatalog, which reads the Normal.gxt on startup, the Normal.mxt should be ignored.

Comment: Your answer made me curious about opening Normal.mxt so I tried to and ArcMap 10.1 will not allow me to open that type of file.

Comment: You can't open/edit mxt or gxt [anymore](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52446/how-can-i-edit-create-new-normal-mxt-template-in-arcgis-10-1), just save new ones. At least I can't. I also deleted the leftover 10.1 folders to check (only previous version), and that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have administrative privileges on the machine you are working on? I am running Arc 10.1 and am able to open and edit my Normal.mxt file. However this probably will not help the question as this seems to be a 10.2 issue

Comment: Yes, I have full adminstrative rights. That isn't the issue though - Arc won't even *see* that extension. I should make a technical correction here. You *can* open it through Explorer, but you cannot actually Save it aside from making a change, closing Arc, and clicking yes if/when prompted - which is what happens anyway every time Arc is closed (your changes made that session are saved to *your* normal.mxt).