# Saving Customized Toolbars

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

I am trying to put together toolbars with model builder tools I created. I followed the instructions on ESRI's page, but it doesn't seem to want to save.

I created the toolbar in ArcCatalog, as well, and it saves fine. ArcMap doesn't recognize that it was created after I close the mxd. I want to have it available for all mxds, and not just the one I save it to.

Edit: The save when I save the MXD, but I want it to save to every MXD I open, not just the one I saved with it loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to replace the `Normal.mxt` file with something customized, similar to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52446/editing-creating-new-normal-mxt-template-in-arcgis-for-desktop). `Normal.mxt` is what you see as "Blank Map" upon opening ArcMap, and is the default template chosen if you cancel out of the Getting Started window.

[image: select template window]

Unfortunately, creating and editing `.mxt` files has been disabled since the update to version 10.x. The only real option is to save your customization to your `.mxd` file and move a copy of it to the **Templates** folder.

When you open a template from this window, it merely pulls in its configuration to the new **Untitled** project, so you are free to edit and adjust without risking harm to your custom configuration.

I made a custom toolbar with some models in it and followed this process. Upon opening ArcMap and selecting the new template, I found the custom toolbar and all models in place.

[image]

It's not an ideal solution, and won't apply your configuration to existing `.mxd` documents, but can at least make it simpler for any new projects you create.

Comment: Thank you! I saw some instructions on ESRI's Support page about overwriting the .mxt, but they didn't work. It didn't specify which version it should work with. I tried to replicate the settings from ArcCatalog , since I was able to save it there, but that didn't work either. I figured I could save the .mxd file, but didn't want to have to keep opening it and Save As... every time. I will try to move it to my Templates folders.